# fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "Query"

Tags: graphql-js, relayjs, relay, relaymodern, react-relay

Trying out relay with react and ran into this today. Here is what I've done so far.

Root Query:

```
query {
  tasks {
    id
    taskName
    taskStatus
    userId
  }
}
```

React component hierarchy

```
App   
 ↳--TaskList (props: tasks)
    ↳--TaskListItem (props: task)
```

Now due to the principle of colocation I know I have to write fragments in each component to describe their data needs.

TaskListItem.js

```
const TaskListItemContainer = createFragmentContainer(
    TaskListItem,
    graphql`
        fragment TaskListItem_task on task {
            id
            taskName
            taskDone
            authorId
        }
    `
);
```

TaskList.js

```
const TaskListContainer = createFragmentContainer(
    TaskList,
    graphql`
        fragment TaskList_tasks on task {
            tasks {
                ...TaskListItem_task
            }
        }
    `
);
```

App.js

```
<QueryRenderer
   environment={relayEnvironment}
   query={graphql`
       query AppQuery {
         ...TaskList_tasks
       }
     `
   }
```

When I run the relay compiler I get the following error.

```
Fragment "TaskList_tasks" cannot be spread here as objects of type "Query" can never be of type "task".

App.js (3:15)
2:             query AppQuery {
3:               ...TaskList_tasks
                 ^
4:             }
```

Not able to figure out how to organize the structure because of this problem. Should I modify the schema just to facilitate the structure and reuse of fragments on the client side?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A basic Fragment consists of five things:

- the `fragment` keyword
- the name of the Fragment
- the `on` keyword
- the type the Fragment applies to
- the selection set wrapped in a set of curly brackets

The selection set is one or more fields of the type you specify that you want to request when you use the Fragment. Think of the Fragment as a drop in replacement for a single selection set. If I have a query like this:

```
query {
  foo
  bar
}
```

then `{ foo bar }` is the selection set I'm requesting, in this case on the `Query` type (or whatever your query root operation type is called in your schema). So if I want to use a fragment, I would write:

```
query {
  ...QueryFields
}

fragment QueryFields on Query {
  foo
  bar
}
```

In your code, you're trying to write a query like:

```
query {
  ...TaskList_tasks
}
```

However, as the error indicates, the type associated with the `TaskList_tasks` fragment is `task`. But you're not replacing a selection set for a `task` type here, you're replacing a selection set for the `Query` type. So your request is not valid.

**TLDR;** You need to change the type on your Fragment to `Query`:

```
fragment TaskList_tasks on Query {
  tasks {
    ...TaskListItem_task
  }
}
```